# Is there a way to check the connect ability of a BLE device in Xamarin.Forms (Plugin.BLE)?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there a way to check the connect ability of a BLE device in Xamarin.Forms (I'm using Plugin.BLE)? I need a method (similar to isConnactable) that will check the connect ability of each element from the ObservableCollection. I'm developing an Android application, so cross-platform is not necessary.

Sample illustration in code:

```
ObservableCollection<IDevice> DevicesList = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
ObservableCollection<IDevice> IsConnactableDevicesList = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
DevicesList = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
IsConnactableDevicesList = IfDeviceConnactable(DevicesList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the connectable property sent in the advertising packet? (i.e. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult#isConnectable()). It seems your chosen library does not expose that info. You can skip the plugin and call the native Android framework directly to get this working, since you don't need cross platform compatibility anyway.

You can also modify the plugin to make it expose this info.